# Partial view remains active after close

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I have a view in which I have a kendo-grid, in this grid there is a button to open a detail window. When the button is pressed the detail window opens which is a kendo-window which renders a partial view. When I close the kendo-window I destroy it and set it to null. However I have a JavaScript function on both my view and my partial view that catches the input of a scanner. If I scan while the window with the partial view is open the function on the view does nothing, however when I close the partial view the JavaScript function on the partial view still catches my scans and it tries to process the scan for both pages at once. How can I make sure the partial view is really closed so that it doesn't catch my scan input (preferably with JavaScript).

Partial view action method:

```
public ActionResult GetKendoWindow(int ID, int PID)
{
  //fill and return partial view locationswindow
  ViewBag.ID = ID;
  ViewBag.PID = PID;
  IEnumerable<BinLocationItemModel> model = dbLogic.getItemLocations(PID, ID);

  return PartialView("_PartialViewLocation", model);
}
```

Kendo-window:

```
function showDetails(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (wnd) {
  wnd.close();
}    
var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
wndOpen = 1;

$("#detcont").append("<div id='Details'></div>");

wnd = $("#Details").kendoWindow({
  width: "60%",
  height: "60%",
  actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize", "Close"],
  title: "Location Data for: " + dataItem.ArticleID,
  content: {
    url: "GetKendoWindow",
    type: "GET",
    data: { ID: dataItem.LineNum, PID: dataItem.PickID }
  },
  close: function (e) {
    wnd.destroy();
    wnd = null;
    setWindowInactive();
  }
}).data("kendoWindow");

wnd.center().open();

}

function setWindowInactive(e) {    
wndOpen = 0;
}
```

Partial View JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Scanner opvangen
  $(document).ready(function () {
      if ($('#ItemLocGrid') != null) {
          var pressed = false;
          var chars = [];
          var grid = $('#ItemLocGrid').data('kendoGrid');
          var dataitem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());

          $(window).keypress(function (e) {
              if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) {
                  if (chars.length < 3) {
                      // do nothing
                  } else {

                      $('.focus :input').focus();
                  }
                  chars.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
              }
              if (pressed == false) {
                  setTimeout(function () {
                      if (chars.length >= 5) {
                          var barcode = chars.join("");
                          document.getElementById("txtBarcodes").value = barcode;
                          $('.focus :input').submit();
                      }
                      chars = [];
                      pressed = false;
                      document.getElementById("txtBarcodes").value = "";
                  }, 200);
              }
              pressed = true;
          });
      }
  });

  $('#txtBarcodes').submit(function (e) {
      var grid = $("#ItemLocGrid").data("kendoGrid");
      var dataSource = $("#ItemLocGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
      var allData = grid.dataSource.data();
      var code = this.value;
      var notification = $("#notification").data("kendoNotification");
      console.log("Nothing to see here");
  })
```

Comment: Set the `.html()` of your `Details` to `""`

Comment: Can you show partialview's code?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null on `document.getElementById("txtBarcodes").value = "";` it shouldn't do this however since the window is already 'closed'.

Comment: I'm confused. What is your problem again, this just means, that you are trying to get the value of element with name "txtBarcodes", that not defined (yet).

Comment: my main page catches a barcode scanner' input unless my partial view is open. I also catch the barcode scanner' input with my partial view, however when I close the window with the partial view the JavaScript from that partial view still catches my scanner' input.

Comment: Why are you repeating same thing, over and over again? If your partial view's javascript located directly in it, you can empty out the div, where your partial view has placed (`<div id="Details"></div>`), it will also clears your partial view's javascript code.

Comment: isn't that what `$("#Details").html("");` is supposed to do?

Comment: yes, it's supposed to clear you partial views code, but it seems not your problem, your problem is clear javascript that remains in cache, when you closing your partial view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156016/discussion-between-alim-and-sem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't exactly like SeM mentioned but his code gave me the idea which fixed it. What I did was put my JavaScript code from my partial view into my view(instead of the layout), I didn't realize my view would be able to read a kendo-grid without actually containing it in its code but it actually can. After that it was just a matter of checking if the window is open and processing a scan for either the partial view or the view.

Comment: I've edited my answer, what I was trying to say, that you need to define section (`@RenderSection("scripts", false)`), just before closing `body` tag, which will allow you to override the scripts in your *NOT* partial view, and the code that I posted, you should have to put it on your not partial view.

Comment: You don't need to add references in your Layout, unless you want to that scripts load on every page (which are using that layout).

Answer (score 1):

Empty your `html` inside `Details` div:

```
close: function (e) {
    . . .
    $("#Details").html("");
    . . .
}
```

What is `return PartialView("_PartialViewLocation", model);` doing, is just returning generated html, from your partial view.

### UPDATE

The real problem here is, that you should avoid referencing any scripts in partials. So you need to define a section somewhere in your Layout, for example just before the closing `</body>`, which will allow views (not partial) to include some custom scripts. Then in the view (not partial) you can override this section to include custom scripts:

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Comment: It still tries to write away data in the partial view's JS on scanning after adding this.